# Problems with multiple mySQL inserts

Tags: mysql, content-management-system, last-insert-id

I'm building a simple cms and I'm trying to automatically create an additional in the database when a user signs up. The code worked just fine, with the first insert line, but once I added a second one, it stopped working. I got this code structure from StackOverflow and I've looked on other sites and it seems to be correct, but for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong. Any suggestions?

```
$registerquery = mysql_query("BEGIN
INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, EmailAddress) 
VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."')
INSERT INTO pages (page_title, page_owner) 
VALUES ('My New Page', LAST_INSERT_ID())
COMMIT");
```

Comment: Please do some research on SQL injection attacks.

Comment: You can't do this.  One statement per database call.  If you need them as part of a transaction, make a database call for `BEGIN` and a `COMMIT`/ `ROLLBACK` when you're done, (assuming you're using an engine that supports transactions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't issue two queries in a single query() call with the MySQL driver in PHP. It's a security measure against certain forms of [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) attacks - which your code is vulnerable to (unless you're doing mysql_real_escape_string() or similar earlier).

You're also missing a `;` to separate the two queries.

Multi-query syntax is

```
query1; query2; query3; etc...
```

You've basically got

```
query1 query2
```

which is simply a syntax error.